# Should there be a comma, full stop or semi-colon after 'reality'?

Tags: punctuation

It takes a while to bring myself back into reality, the last few moments having past with such violent surrealism.

Comment: comma, also 'passed' ('past' is the spelling for the noun)

Comment: When you reverse this sentence: _The last few moments having passed with such violent surrealism, it takes a while to bring myself back into reality_ you'll see your latter clause cannot stand alone, therefore you cannot separate it with semi-colon.

Comment: I think that for most people a full stop comes after reality.

Comment: @Hot Licks: that leaves the remainder as a sentence fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while to bring myself back into reality; the last few moment having past with such violent surrealism.

It takes a while to bring myself back into reality, the last few moment having past with such violent surrealism.

It takes a while to bring myself back into reality. The last few moment having past with such violent surrealism.

It would make sense to put a semicolon after reality, because it can be both one large statement and two separate sentences.

Comment: Please see the comments by Mitch and Kathy above for succinct remarks about (1) the need to change the spelling of _past_ to _passed_ in the example, and (2) the preferability of a comma to either a semicolon or a period in this case.